# What is the bleu score of professional human translators?

Tags: nlp, machine-translation

Machine translation models are usually evaluated using bleu score. I want to get some intuition for this score. What is the bleu score of professional human translator?

I know it depends on the languages, the translator ect. I just want to get the scale.

edit: I want to make it clear - I talk about the expected bleu. It's not a theoretical question, it is an experimental one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The original paper ["BLEU: a Method for Automatic Evaluation of Machine Translation"](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040.pdf) contains a couple of numbers on this:

> The BLEU metric ranges from 0 to 1. Few translations will attain a score of 1 unless they are identical to a reference translation. For this reason, even
>   a human translator will not necessarily score 1. It
>   is important to note that the more reference translations per sentence there are, the higher the score is. Thus, one must be cautious making even “rough”
>   comparisons on evaluations with different numbers
>   of reference translations: on a test corpus of about
>   500 sentences (40 general news stories), **a human
>   translator scored 0.3468 against four references and
>   scored 0.2571 against two references**.

But as their table 1 (providing the numbers compared to two references, H2 is the one mentioned in the text above) shows there is variance among human BLEU scores:

[image]

Unfortunately, the paper does not qualify the skill level of the translators.

Comment: Thanks. Notice that the table might be confusing without saying that h1, h2 are human translations and s1, s2, s3 are machine translations. For the other readers I will also mention it is chinese-english translation task.

Answer (score 5):

BLEU scores are based on comparing the translation to evaluate against a gold-standard translation. In general the gold-standard translation is the same source sentence translated by a professional translator, so in theory a professional human translation should always receive the maximum score of 1 (BLEU scores are normalized between 0 and 1).

However it's important to keep in mind that:

- Even professional translators don't always agree on what is the "correct" translation, so there's no perfect evaluation method.
- There can be multiple valid translations for the same sentences. This can be taken into account in the BLEU score, but most of the time BLEU scores are calculated using a single translation. As a consequence it's possible that a perfectly good translation gets a low score.
- BLEU scores are based on counting the number of n-grams in common between the predicted translation and the gold-standard. It's a quite good proxy for translation quality, but it's also very basic. In particular it cannot take the meaning into account.

Comment: Thanks. I already knew what you said. I want to know what is the expected bleu of a translator - if I take two different translators and measure the translation of one of them (choose his randomly) against the "gold translation" of the other what is the average bleu. It won't be 1 because the translations may not be exactly the same.

Comment: @AmitKeinan Yes, that's why I mentioned that professional translators don't always agree. That means that there can be no general answer to your question: since the score *depends on which translation is chosen as reference*, it could be anywhere between 0 and 1. But there's no reason to choose one professional translation rather than the other, so in theory the logic of BLEU score is that a professional translation has perfect score.

Comment: well, maybe you don't understand my question. I know it can be anywhere between 0 and 1 - it is a probabalistic question. My question is about expectation. If I will take many translators, split them to couples and measure the bleu between the translations, what will be the avergae score? I want an answer with real experimental references.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't understand that indeed. Still, any experimental value depends on the data and the translators, there's no universal answer.

Comment: @Erwan it's also worth noting that BLEU as such does not depend on which translation is chosen as reference, it's designed to take into account multiple equally valid reference translations - it's just that in most practical applications we don't have more than one reference translation available.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned above, it depends on many variables. Not only level of translators' expertise but also length and type of source text, the provider of reference translation etc. can play a  role. According to my experiments translators' BLEU score lies ca. between 0.021~0.02703. In my experiments subjects were students of Graduate school of Translation and we had only one reference translation for each case. It is almost impossible that BLEU score goes up to 1 in a natural translation-evaluation situation.
Hye-Yeon Chung (2020). Automatic Evaluation of Human Translation: BLEU vs. METEOR. Lebende Sprachen 65(1).